# Simple Rewrite Rule issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a bit of hard time trying to understand what is wrong with the 3rd line of this rewrite rule :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fr/lecon-de-kite\.html$ kite-lessons.php?lang=fr [L]
RewriteRule ^fr$ index.php?lang=fr [L]
RewriteRule ^it$ index.php?lang=it [L]
```

when I try to reach http://localhost/kitemeup/fr/lecon-de-kite.html I get an **Not Found** error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it like this in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^fr/lecon-de-kite\.html$ kite-lessons.php?lang=fr [L]
RewriteRule ^(it|fr)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Just understand that ordering of rules is important as mod_rewrite processes them from top to bottom. Your `html -> php` rule was taking precedence and converting all `.html` URIs to `.php` making your 2nd rule ineffective.